# Use Pillow resize with an ImageField

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, imagefield

I am new to python and trying to use `ImageField` in my model. I have some images in files separate from my Django Project that I want to upload.

So I have a Django model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    img_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images',
                                      blank=True, null=True)
```

In my conversion code which uploads images, I want to generate thumbnails at a specific height so I can not use:

```
img = Image.open(file_path)
img.thumbnail()
```

Instead, I calculate the necessary width and resize it using Pillow.

```
img = Image.open(file_path)
h_percent = (75/ float(img.size[1]))
if h_percent < 1:
    width = int((float(img.size[0]) * float(h_percent)))
    img = img.resize((width, base_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
filename = os.path.basename(file_path)
```

That works fine but when I tried to save that to an ImageField, I get an error: AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'content'

```
product.img_thumbnail.save(filename, img, True)
```

Searching the web, I found reference to SimpleUploadedFile. So write the resized image with a suffix. I received another error; : 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 251: character maps to

```
file_root, file_ext = os.path.splitext(file_path)
new_file_name = file_root + '_thumbnail' + file_ext
img.save(new_file_name)
filename = os.path.basename(file_path)
with open(new_file_name) as infile:
    _file = SimpleUploadedFile(filename, infile.read())
```

So what should I do here? I am using Python 3.6 with Django 2.0
Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you trying to have django auto-generate thumbnails for images uploaded by users? If so, I would suggest reading up on the `post_save` signal. I also wrote a [blog post](https://blog.pursuitofzen.com/auto-pdf-to-png-in-django/) that addresses using a `post_save` hook. Lastly, looking at your `save` implementation, the documentation requires the 2nd argument to be a content, where content should be an instance of `django.core.files.File`. However, I would just use the `post_save` hook to just save the entire model object.

Comment: Currently, I am not working with images upload by users. This is conversion code run once before the site is deployed. It takes files from a source directory, not part of the Django project, then resizes those images as it iterates through the products. Thanks for responding though as I will definitely look at your blog post when I work on the user upload.

Comment: Ugh! I must have tried to do this a dozen different ways. Fortunately, one of them worked but I didn't realize it because of a spelling error in my template. Now, I have to recall them to see which one worked.